# Problem while using multirow with graphics

Tags: graphics, arrays, multirow

I have a problem with the multirow command.

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{1}
&
\multirow{2}{*}{
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{3}
}
\\
\hline
\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{2}
& \\
\end{array}
```

results in this

```
|1| |
---3-
|2|3|
   3
   3
```

[image: problem 1]

How to obtain the following :

```
|1|3|
---3-
|2|3|
| |3|
```

[image: Wanted]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You *can* add images with the normal interface (click on the button); just remove the `!` that appears automatically. A user with enough reputation will reinstate it.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the images. Now I will wait for someone to make them displayable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `\multirow`, but rather the `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=1.3in]{a}\\[2ex]
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=0.7in]{b}
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
&
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
  \includegraphics[width=1.5in,height=1.7in]{c}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

With `valign=t` we're shifting the reference point of the inner `tabular` and of the image to the right to their top.

Note. I've used `height` and the `demo` option just to produce mock figures; don't use them yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is described here https://newbedev.com/placing-a-figure-inside-a-multirow-table-cell

In essence, the author suggests using `[<fixup>]` parameter of `multirow` like in the following:

```latex
\multirow{2}{*}[0.5in]{\includegraphics[width=2in]{...}}
```